# SerialPort.DataRecieved Event not triggering C#

Tags: c#, event-handling, serial-port

I am trying to implement the following piece of code in order to capture information incoming to me through a serial connection. Im using the .NET SerialPort class:

```
//serial port initialization           
serialPort = new SerialPort();    

serialPort.PortName = "COM7";
serialPort.BaudRate = 19200;
serialPort.Parity = Parity.Even;
serialPort.DataBits = 8;
serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
serialPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;



//this is how the handler is added in Form1.Designer.cs
this.serialPort.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(this.DataReceivedHandler);


//Handler
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Got Here");
        while (serialPort.BytesToRead > 0)
        {
            byteBuffer.Add((byte)serialPort.ReadByte());
            ProcessByteBuffer(byteBuffer);
        }

    }
```

I physically connected my Rx and Tx pins on the RS232 port, and im trying to write a message to trigger the event to see if its working. I can't seem to get the event to trigger the "Got Here" text never appears in my console. I know the data is going into my recieve buffer because i can call serialPort.ReadExisting() and see the message I originally input.

Can anyone tell me why this event might not be firing?

Comment: Please provide more information about how you have instantiated the `SerialPort` itself and also the way you have added the `handler`?

Comment: have you tried using putty or hyperterminal to connect to your port?

Comment: I had the same problem, didn't find a solution and ended up pinging the com port in a background thread to see if there was any data.

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh I added a bit more information to clarify.

Comment: @Arie no I have not, I have simply shorted the tx and rx line to simulate the PC recieving data when it has been written. I know it works because I can read the output string the same as it was inputted, its just that the event isnt triggering.

Comment: @user1296932 First try removing the handler and add it again. Second instead of writing something to the Console, put a `BreakPoint` to see whether it is triggering or not. because it might be triggered but can not send the data to the output. Third reduce your BaudRate to the 9600. Fourth do not configure `serialPort.Handshake` and `serialPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold`. Let them be their default value.

Comment: I noticed that you have Parity set. try subscribing to ErrorReceived event and check if you don't have parity or other errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 serialPort = new SerialPort();
```

You got that wrong.  You *overwrote* the SerialPort object reference that designer created.  The one that had the DataReceived event assigned.  Your *new* object doesn't have that event assigned.  So it will never fire.

Just delete that line.